# Email when a Site Page is published as news on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

We use SharePoint Online as a module of Office 365. We have a 2013 classic team site on our root collection and the home page is a modern home page with a new-style News web part.

In Site Pages library, we have the option of creating a Wiki Page, Web Part Page or Site Page. We are creating a Site Page and then publishing it. Immediately after publication, SharePoint Online prompts us to Post as News on this site. For most site pages, we click on Post as News on this site.

[image]

**Question:**
How can we automatically send an email to notify a person or group that a news article was published?

**My attempt**

1. I tried to use Microsoft Flow to sniff properties, on a file that was created or modified, with the hope of identifying whether the published page was published as news. Content Type property shows Site Page for Site Page that is and that is not published as news. So, that didn't help.
2. I tried sniffing Promoted State, and that didn't uniquely identify a news page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by waiting for "Promoted State" to equal 2 in a Do-Until loop where I have:  Delay 1 minute, Get [updated] File Properties, and then check to see if PromotedState = 2.

The trick is to make sure you "Get file properties" inside the Do-Until loop, otherwise the initial value (0) will continue to be evaluated until it times out.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I got an opportunity to test a SharePoint 2013 workflow on SharePoint 365. I used `Pause until variable/time` logic to wait until a certain time and retry. Promoted State of 2 was detected when site page was published. Great job. Thank you for the help.